# Django Templates - How to auto increment an integer?

Tags: django, django-templates, alpine.js

I'm using Django with Alpine.js. I'm trying to loop over users' images from 1 to 20. For instance, 'user-1.jpg', 'user-2.jpg', and so on and so forth. The following is, of course, not working, but at least it will give you a sense of what I'm trying to achieve:

```py
{% load static %}

<div x-data="libs.testimonialsCircles()">

<template x-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" hidden>
  <img class="absolute rounded-full z-10 animate-float" :style="item.style" :src="`{% static img/user-${index+1}.jpg %}`" :width="item.size" :height="item.size" :alt="`User ${index+1}`" @mouseenter="active = index; commentOn = true" @mouseleave="commentOn = false" />
</template>

</div>
```

#### My JS file

```js
export default function testimonialsCircles() {
  return {
    commentOn: false,
    active: 0,
    // each item is a testimonial avatar with a comment
    items: [
      {
        // user-1.jpg
        img: 'user-1.jpg',
        size: '48', // image width / height
        style: 'max-width: 7.08%;top: 29%;left: 2%;', // image absolute  positioning
        comment:
          'A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. ', // comment to be displayed on hover,
        name: 'Elian Whitney',
      },
      {
        // user-2.jpg
        size: '36',
        style: 'max-width:5.31%;top: 60%;left: 2%;',
        comment:
          'Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts.',
        name: 'Justice Porter',
      },
      {
        // user-3.jpg
        size: '72',
        style: 'max-width: 10.62%;top: 43%;left: 13%;',
        comment:
          'When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream.',
        name: 'Leonel Roy',
      },
      {
        // user-4.jpg
        size: '56',
        style: 'max-width: 8.26%;top: 75%;left: 14%;',
        comment:
          'O my friend -- but it is too much for my strength -- I sink under the weight of the splendour.',
        name: 'Daniel Wolf',
      },
      {
        // user-5.jpg
        size: '64',
        style: 'max-width: 9.44%;top: 11%;left: 15%;',
        comment:
          'I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine.',
        name: 'Seamus Miranda',
      },
      {
        // user-6.jpg
        size: '80',
        style: 'max-width: 11.8%;top: 32%;left: 30%;',
        comment:
          'I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents.',
        name: 'Fiona Schultz',
      },
      {
        // user-7.jpg
        size: '50',
        style: 'max-width: 7.37%;top: 65%;left: 30%;',
        comment:
          'I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment.',
        name: 'Monica Evans',
      },
      {
        // user-8.jpg
        size: '36',
        style: 'max-width:5.31%;top: 6%;left: 33%;',
        comment: 'I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.',
        name: 'Jakayla Dunlap',
      },
      {
        // user-9.jpg
        size: '44',
        style: 'max-width: 6.49%;top: 77%;left: 44%;',
        comment:
          'When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees.',
        name: 'Mattie Sharp',
      },
      {
        // user-10.jpg
        size: '64',
        style: 'max-width: 9.44%;top: 48%;left: 46%;',
        comment:
          'I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.',
        name: 'Jazmyn Gaines',
      },
      {
        // user-11.jpg
        size: '72',
        style: 'max-width: 10.62%;top: 16%;left: 46%;',
        comment:
          'One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin.',
        name: 'Patrick Christensen',
      },
      {
        // user-12.jpg
        size: '64',
        style: 'max-width: 9.44%;top: 65%;left: 58%;',
        comment:
          'His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked.',
        name: 'Mike Johnson',
      },
      {
        // user-13.jpg
        size: '80',
        style: 'max-width: 11.8%;top: 32%;left: 62%;',
        comment:
          'His room, a proper human room although a little too small, lay peacefully between its four familiar walls.',
        name: 'Lyla Griffith',
      },
      {
        // user-14.jpg
        size: '48',
        style: 'max-width: 7.08%; top: 6%;left: 63%;',
        comment:
          'Drops of rain could be heard hitting the pane, which made him feel quite sad.',
        name: 'Damien Mclaughlin',
      },
      {
        // user-15.jpg
        size: '24',
        style: 'max-width: 3.54%;top: 93%;left: 65%;',
        comment:
          '" He felt a slight itch up on his belly; pushed himself slowly up on his back towards the headboard so that he could lift his head better.',
        name: 'Perry Mason',
      },
      {
        // user-16.jpg
        size: '36',
        style: 'max-width:5.31%;top: 86%;left: 76%;',
        comment:
          'For instance, whenever I go back to the guest house during the morning to copy out the contract, these gentlemen are always still sitting there eating their breakfasts. I ought to just try that with my boss.',
        name: 'Briana Friedman',
      },
      {
        // user-17.jpg
        size: '44',
        style: 'max-width: 6.49%;top: 59%;left: 76%;',
        comment:
          'I would get kicked out on the spot.But who knows, maybe that would be the best thing for me.',
        name: 'Manuel Kirk',
      },
      {
        // user-18.jpg
        size: '72',
        style: 'max-width: 10.62%;top: 14%;left: 78%;',
        comment:
          'And it is a funny sort of business to be sitting up there at your desk, talking down at your subordinates from up there.',
        name: 'Cedric Reynolds',
      },
      {
        // user-19.jpg
        size: '64',
        style: 'max-width: 9.44%;top: 40%;left: 89%;',
        comment: 'I ought to just try that with my boss.',
        name: 'Gracelyn Wilcox',
      },
      {
        // user-20.jpg
        size: '24',
        style: 'max-width: 3.54%;top: 74%;left: 91%;',
        comment:
          'It was half past six and the hands were quietly moving forwards, it was even later than half past.',
        name: 'Jamir Henson',
      },
    ],
  };
}
```

I know that I probably should use `{{ forloop.counter }}` but I'm not sure how exactly should I use it in this type of context.

Comment: Where are you taking your `items` variable from and how does it look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: `:src="\`{% static img/user-${index+1}.jpg %}\`"` cannot work. You're mixing client and server state. Django does not have access to the index variable as its only generated by Alpine.js on the frontend. But, as your image URLs are apparently deterministic, you can pass your file static path to your frontend via the `testimonialsCircles`function, for example via a `staticImagesURL` variable. In your template, you can then dynamically build the image url with `:src="\`${staticImagesURL}/user-${index+1}.jpg\`"` or `:src="\`${staticImagesURL}/${item.img}\`"`.